# I need to select a particular row in a table with selenium webriver

Tags: webdriver

I need to select  a particular row in a table with selenium web driver, I have close to 5000 rows, Navigating through each row would be difficult. Any better approach if we have?

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on a checkbox to select the row right?
I'll assume thats what you meant:
The only way I know how is to check each row, select the filter (i.e. a customer number) and once you find it, click on the selection checkbox.
Mostly of the tables are similar so here is an example:

## This is your table:

```
    =           =               =             =                 =                       =           = 
    =================================================================================================
    =           =               =             =                 =                       =           = 
    =================================================================================================
    =           =               =             =                 =                       =           = 
    =================================================================================================
    Lets say that in the first row, is where the checkbox is, and that in the second row is the location of the filter.
    meaning the data you will use in order to know that this is the row you need....

    you will need to inspect the table element in order to find its ID, once you have that info you can use a similar method as the below:
    Where you will use your webdriver, data filter, tableID and the number of the column where your data filter is located.
    The method will return the row you need to click, then you can simply use the row[columnNumberLocation].Click() in order to select it.

public IWebElement returnRow(IWebDriver webDriver, string filter ,string tableName, int i)
    {

        IWebElement tableElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(tableName));
        IWebElement tbodyElement = tableElement.FindElement(By.TagName("TBODY"));

        List<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>(tbodyElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            List<IWebElement> cells = new List<IWebElement>(row.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));

            if (cells.Count > 0)
            {
                string s = cells[i].Text;
                if (s.Equals(filter))
                {
                    return row;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is your requirement of selecting that particular row.

I assume you need to select that according to the row index.
So it's all about the your x-path to locate the element.

ex: I need to get row number 2000

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2000]"));`